# display:none, drop-down-menus and screen-readers

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, accessibility, screen-readers

I have often read that using *display:none* for drop-down-menus (like done [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp)) is bad practice, because it is inaccessible for screen-readers.

In this article: http://simplyaccessible.com/article/better-for-accessibility/ the author states that the position-off-left alternative from *display:none* has also downsides and suggests the following to make the drop-down-menu keyboard accessible:

> Option 2: use display:none and have a :focus state to match :hover
>   that makes it display:block and brings the sub menu items onto the
>   page, allowing them to receive the focus, but only while they are on
>   the screen.

The *:focus* adjustment is realized with JavaScript. He gives an example on http://examples.simplyaccessible.com/css-menu/option-2.php.

**Question 1:**
Is the drop-down-menu from option 2 accessible for screen-readers? Do screen-reader read the complete page, and then you can tab through the page and they read out ever link? Would this means that the sub-menu is only read by the screen-reader when the person tabs through?

**Question 2:**
Using *display:none* has for me the great advantage that I can use jQuery functions like *.slideDown()* and *.slideUp()* which add a nice animation effect on the drop-down-menu. If I use *position:absolute* and hide the sub-menus off-left, how could I then get nice animation affects similar to *.slideDown()* and *.slideUp()*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer 1:** The simple answer is yes.

**Longer answer:**

Screen readers have a lot of options to move around a page, list out all of the available anchors, etc. NVDA, for example, also reads information via mouse interaction. Often, though, the focus of accessibility discussion is on keyboard users since they are often forgotten by developers. If a user is tabbing through the page, anchors that are visible (not display none) can have focus and be read. So the sub-menu is only accessible to the keyboard user (in option 2) when tabbing through the navigation. This applies to both visual and screen reader keyboard users. You can add your own keyboard interactions so content is available beyond tabs. However, keep in mind that the end user may not know how to use the menu. You'll also want to be mindful of keys already bound to screen readers.

**Answer 2:** Simple answer - you may want to consider CSS3 animations/transitions.

**Explanation:**

The slide aspect can be animated (if you have variable heights) using max-height and overflow hidden. So by default max-height of the sub-menu is 0 and then when the class is added you can set it to a number you think makes sense.

```
.menu li { position:relative; }
.sub-menu {
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  max-height:0;
  opacity:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  transition:all 0.3s ease-in;
}
.active > .sub-menu { max-height:99em; opacity:1; }
```

If you make it 9999px the transition/animation look and feel will be influenced differently than 250px. Below is a simple CSS example of this:

**Longer discussion point:**

There wouldn't be much benefit for hiding the menu with position absolute off-left vs. display none for menus, if using an approach similar to the option you mentioned. You could get into a discussion on when JS is disabled and needing the content available then. Display none by default would prevent keyboard users from getting the content still (screen readers do understand Javascript, though). But the JS debate opens up further dilemmas, if we really want this to be perfect for all users without Javascript with different situations. With the content only visually hidden with the position absolute off left approach, a keyboard user who is a visual user will be able to focus on the anchors but won't ever see the content and may get lost (since it remains off screen).

So it isn't easy if we really want to account for all users in all situations. We have to set some restrictions sometimes and progressive enhancement is a possible aspect to keep in mind. Maybe the sub menus are only available to Javascript users. If interior pages have rail navigation of the sub section links then non-JS users regardless of screen reader user or visual keyboard user can still access all of the pages of the site.

Comment: Great answer! On the last point "progressive enhancement" is the most important. Sadly there are [so many websites](https://medium.com/@fox/the-web-isn-t-uniform-fd67eb631501#.734nfxcs1) out there you can't use with disabled javascript, so please try to start by using only CSS and [unobtrusive javascript](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). Start with focus on keyboard/tab navigation and if javascript is enabled enhance the accessibility furthermore...